# How to do two delete operation based on condition in spring boot webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to have a delete operation(r2dbc) using Webflux based on the condition as below, but switchIf empty is not working as expected. **Specific Items are deleted successfully** is getting printed always irrespective of filter condition satisfies or not.

```
Mono.just(cart).filter(cart1 -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(cart1.getItems()))
    .flatMapMany(cartV->Flux.fromIterable(cartV.getCartItems())).flatMap(items -> deleteItemsByIdName(id, items))
    .then(Mono.just("Specific Items are deleted successfully")).log().switchIfEmpty(deleteAllItems(id).then(Mono.just("All Items are deleted successfully"))).log();
```

Kindly let me know, what I am missing here.. Or I need to change the logic completely?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `switchIfEmpty` works exactly like it should. The problem you have is caused by `.then(Mono.just("Specific Items are deleted successfully"))`. [then](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--) method sends a given `Mono` upon receiving the complete signal from upstream publisher. In other words, when your condition is not met, then the `cart` items are not converted to `Flux` and they are not deleted, but the message is logged anyway. Take a look at [doOnNext](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) and see if sth like that works:

```
Mono.just(cart)
                .filter(cart1 -> CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(cart1.getItems()))
                .flatMapMany(cartV -> Flux.fromIterable(cartV.getCartItems()))
                .flatMap(item -> deleteItemsByIdName(id, item)
                        .doOnNext(res -> log.info("Item " + item + " has been removed"))
                )
                .switchIfEmpty(deleteAllItems(id).doOnNext(res -> log.info("All items have been removed")));
```